# Find $ \bigcup_{i = 1}^\infty A_{i} $ and $ \bigcap_{i = 1}^\infty A_{i} $ if for every positive integer $i$, $A_{i} = \left\{ {-i, i}\right\}$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

This is a question from Rosen's *Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications*. It asks:

> Find $ \bigcup_{i = 1}^\infty A_{i} $ and $ \bigcap_{i = 1}^\infty A_{i} $ if for every positive integer $i$, $A_{i} = \left\{ {-i, i}\right\}$.

For the first question I worked out the following:

> $ \bigcup_{i = 1}^\infty A_{i} = \left\{ {-1, 1}\right\} \cup \left\{ {-2, -1, 1, 2}\right\} \cup \left\{ {-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3}\right\} ... \cup \left\{ {-n, -(n-1), ..., -2, -1, 1, 2, ..., (n-1), n}\right\} $
>
> $ = \mathbb{Z} - \left\{ {0}\right\}$.

Which is the correct answer according to the solutions in the back.

For the second question I worked out the following:

> $ \bigcap_{i = 1}^\infty A_{i} = \left\{ {-1, 1}\right\} \cap \left\{ {-2, -1, 1, 2}\right\} \cap \left\{ {-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3}\right\} ... \cap \left\{ {-n, -(n-1), ..., -2, -1, 1, 2, ..., (n-1), n}\right\} $
>
> $= \left\{ {-1, 1}\right\}$.

This is the wrong answer. The solution in the back says it is the empty set. I have two questions:

(1) Can someone explain to me why the answer is the empty set? The textbook doesn't have a worked solution for this question.

(2) My (probably mistaken) thinking is that the intersection means what the sets have in common. My thinking process is that each set only have the numbers -$1$ and $1$ in common. What's the mistake in my thinking here?

Comment: $A_2=\{-2,2\}$, not $\{-2,-1-,1,2\}$ and similarly for other $A_i'$s. Even in first part you made the same mistake, but you got the answer right ;)

Comment: I know, I feel silly now. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each set $A_i$ only contains two elements; so for example,

$$ A_2 = \{-2, 2\}$$

In your solution, you've replaced this by

$$ A_2 = \{-2, -1, 1, 2\}$$

and similar errors for all other $i > 1$. Hence when you look at what's in common, you'll find nothing.

Comment: So I made a mistake in the first one as well. Thanks for pointing this out. I'll accept your answer when the time limit is up.